# Add feedback textbox to all pages in a sharepoint 2010 wiki library

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am working on creating a SharePoint 2010 site in which I have placed the content in wiki libraries. I want to have a feedback textbox on every page. On clicking submit, there are two options, I can store the feedback text in yet another custom SharePoint list or configure it to send an email.

Please guide me on how to go about adding the feedback textbox ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the out of the box "Note Board" web part in the "Social Collaboration" section.  You can add it to the page layout if you have publishing enabled.  This will add it to every wiki page.

If you don't have publishing enabled, you will have to add the web part to each page individually.

This has the added advantage of leveraging the existing social features in SharePoint 2010.  Meaning you will be able to see the notes you have added from your MySite and it will be shared with colleagues.

Comment: Thanks a ton, this is really good :) I would go ahead and use the same for my site.